# Is std::atomic technically required even if I'm already using std::mutex to guard access?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

It seems like it is technically required to guard all data read/written by multiple threads with `std::atomic` according to the standard, but that seems odd for cases with complex data initialization. Is the following undefined behavior or does using a lock make things ok with respect to the C++ memory model?

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    int x;
    int y;

    static Foo* GetFoo();

private:
    static std::mutex sm_lock;
    static Foo* sm_foo;
};

std::mutex Foo::sm_lock;
Foo* sm_foo = nullptr;

Foo* Foo::GetFoo() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(sm_lock);
    if (!sm_foo) {
        sm_foo = new Foo();
        if (sm_foo) {
            sm_foo->x = 42;
            sm_foo->y = 11;
        }
    }

    return sm_foo;
}
```

I know in practice this will pretty much always work for x86_64, but what about platforms which have weaker memory ordering?

Comment: I'm not saying that you're wrong but can you cite the part of the Standard that makes you think it claims that *it is technically required to guard all data read/written by multiple threads with std::atomic*?

Comment: Re: “It seems like it is technically required to guard all data read/written by multiple threads with std::atomic according to the standard” — not so. Code must prevent data races; there are several ways of doing that. `std::atomic` is one; `std::mutex` is another. The code in the question is correct for all platforms.

Comment: Just to avoid misunderstandings: When actually accessing a member through the pointer returned by `GetFoo` you of course still need to lock the mutex as well (assuming at least one thread may be writing to it).

Comment: @user17732522 for the sake of this question, assume it is only written to in Foo::GetFoo, but it can be read by multiple threads without using the lock (so write once and read many times).

Comment: @DyllonGagnier That's ok as well. (Although then the returned pointer should be `const` to avoid mistakenly violating that assumption.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is std::atomic technically required even if I'm already using std::mutex to guard access?

No, the mutex lock makes it safe - but you don't need to check if `sm_foo` is non-null after `new`. `new` (as used in your example) will throw an exception if it fails:

```cpp
Foo* Foo::GetFoo() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(sm_lock);
    if (!sm_foo) {
        sm_foo = new Foo();    
        sm_foo->x = 42;      // sm_foo can't be a null pointer here
        sm_foo->y = 11;
    }
    return sm_foo;
}
```

An even better method would be to not use a pointer at all. This doesn't require a mutex lock since the instantiation is thread safe (since threads were introduced in the language):

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    int x;
    int y;

    static Foo& GetFoo();

private:
    // if it's supposed to be a singleton:
    Foo(int X, int Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}

    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo operator=(Foo&&) = delete;
    ~Foo() = default;
};

Foo& Foo::GetFoo() {
    static Foo sm_foo{42,11}; // thread safe instantiation
    return sm_foo;
}
```

If you *really* want `GetFoo()` to return a pointer, that's no problem (although it's more common to return a reference to the instance):

```cpp
class Foo {
    // ...
    static Foo* GetFoo();
};

Foo* Foo::GetFoo() {
    static Foo sm_foo{42,11}; // still a thread safe instantiation
    return &sm_foo;
}
```

Comment: @oisyn No, that's exactly what `constinit` is for. However, I removed my comment, because there is a small annoying issue with using `constinit` and `constexpr` on static data members of a type of the enclosing class. It can be circumvented, but is non-obvious.

Comment: @user17732522  You mentioned initialization order too. Initialization order fiascos shouldn't happen with this lazy initialization.

Comment: Yes, the goal was no functional difference, but shorter notation.

Comment: If you want to assure the singleton property, it probably also makes sense to delete the copy/move operations, so that a user doesn't create a second instance that way.

Comment: @user17732522 Very true. I deleted copying. If they want to move or assign it to itself, I'll allow it for now :-)

Comment: Not quite. Declaring the copy constructor caused the move constructor and assignment to vanish. (And they could have moved it away from your control to a new object!)

Comment: @user17732522 They can still move assign or copy assign it to itself. _"they could have moved it away from your control to a new object"_ - What object would that be?

Comment: Yes copy-assign to itself still works, but there will be no move assignment operator or move constructor. If there was a move constructor, they could have done `Foo myFoo = std::move(getFoo());` and now `myFoo` has the state.

Comment: @user17732522 The move _assignment_ is still there. Oh well, I'll delete the lot of them to make it clear :-)

Comment: No, a user-declared copy constructor prevents implicit declaration of a move assignment operator. Basically, the move-part of the rule-of-5 is explicitly enforced (and the copy-part of it is intended to be enforced as well, but currently, and probably forever, that is only deprecated, not removed, behavior).

Comment: @TedLyngmo just for context on why I want to do things this way, static locals like you propose are actually unsafe in many cases when combined with cooperative multiprocessing (i.e. Go/Java vthreads). In my example, you can just replace std::mutex with some custom mutex that is multiprocessing aware (such as a wrapper that has std::mutex plus pin the user thread to the physical thread).

Comment: @user17732522 You're right of course. Mind meltdown over here :)

Comment: @DyllonGagnier Ok, in that case, use what you got. The mutex makes the instantiation with `new` safe. What does the custom mutex look like btw?

Comment: @DyllonGagnier If you are not actually talking about the data races between C++ threads, then the answer doesn't need to be the same. If you are talking about a whole different threading/memory concept, it wouldn't have anything to do with the C++ threading and memory model guarantees.